# Hello,could you tell me how to input the symbols of mathematics in this website?

Tags: support, mathjax

Some people say I need to learn to use mathjax, but I don't know about mathjax.
How can I learn to use mathjax to input the symbols of mathematics,such as the symbols of integral?
   Thank you for your help!

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the basic tutorial / quick-reference.

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).